# 3v/5vDC to 60-70vAC

Tags: inverter, dc-ac

I need to convert 3.3v or 5v to 60v-70vAC (to drive PDLC). The current is very low (few mA).

I have tried EL wire inverter, it worked fine but they also make high pitched noise (I assume from high frequency voltage) which makes it absolutely unusable for my application as silent operation is very important.

Is there any other solution/product to convert 3.3v/5v to 60-70vAC ?

Comment: Buy a inverter ?

Comment: Can you make a 50~100Hz sine oscillator amplifier with a 60+Vdc supply?  Or use a C divider from 240Vac? With plastic Y caps 2 or 3nF to 10nF shunt then a series current limit R to PDLC

Comment: Who has to be unable to hear it? Humans? Dogs? Bats?

Comment: Is the noise continuous, or not ?

Comment: The noise is like this https://youtu.be/FcniCVgOJL0?t=3m55s 
and I need to get rid of that noise

Comment: @Janka The humans

Comment: @TonyStewartEEsince1975 that seems bit too hard for me to understand :( I guess I need simpler way, ideally something ready to be purchased from online stores ( though some basic soldering is fine, just not too hard stuff )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sound comes from the magnetostriction inside the coil core. The frequency of those EL inverters is limited to a few kHz, because EL foils don't like higher frequencies. Not sure about your PDLC.

There are inverters without coils, but the lift from 5V to 60V is too heavy for such a charge pump. +-10V would be feasible for +5V with a LTC3261. Still, you had a DC output then, and PDLC don't like DC.

So, no, from +5V, there's not much you could do electronically. Choosing an EL inverter of good quality and putting it into a noise cancelling box should help.